# Proving a connected graph cannot have only even-degree vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I want to prove that a connected graph with *m* edges and *n* vertices must have at least one vertex of odd degree. In particular, I want to prove this for a graph of 53 edges and 11 vertices; but also in general, is there a way to prove this for a more general case, given a set of parameters for *m* and *n*?

Comment: This isn't true. Consider the complete graph $K_3$ with $3$ vertices and $3$ edges. Each vertex has degree $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already shown, it's not true in general (any simple cycle has every node of even degree).

The case with 53 edges and 11 vertices is particular, since 11*10/2=55, so it's a complete graph without 2 edges, and it's easy to prove that there exists a node with odd degree, since there are basically only 2 cases.

But this reasoning fails very often. For example there exists a graph with 11 vertices and **52** edges that has no nodes of odd degree (try to prove it by yourself ;)  )

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know abut this particular case, but I was wondering if there was some general rule for determining whether a particular graph has any vertices of odd degree. (In particular I wanted to know this in relation to whether a graph is Eulerian or not; I know that every vertex in a graph must be of an even degree in order for a graph to be Eulerian, and so I wanted to know if there was a more general method for proving that a graph with a certain number of vertices and a certain number of edges is Eulerian or not, beyond simply creating a proof for that particular case.)

Comment: @cerremony This is only my guess, but I think that there are very very few cases where all the graphs with $n$ nodes and $m$ edges have an odd degree node.